# enable to use reactstrap library in client side spfx

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, web-parts, reactstrap

I am creating a client-side web part in SharePoint using react and I am getting an error for using reactstrap in it.

[image]

[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "e85e1482-17da-4af0-968f-3f63def88702" (ReactSpfxWebPartWebPart).
Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "e85e1482-17da-4af0-968f-3f63def88702" (ReactSpfxWebPartWebPart).
Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/e85e1482-17da-4af0-968f-3f63def88702_0.0.1
    Cannot read property 'placements' of undefined

***INNERERROR:
***Failed to load entry point from component "e85e1482-17da-4af0-968f-3f63def88702" (ReactSpfxWebPartWebPart).
Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/e85e1482-17da-4af0-968f-3f63def88702_0.0.1
    Cannot read property 'placements' of undefined
***CALLSTACK:
Error
    at SPLoaderError.SPError [as constructor] (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:8668:24)
    at new SPLoaderError (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:4124:28)
    at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:3783:21)
    at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildLoadComponentError (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:3691:21)
    at https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:6936:47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add 
  "externals": {
    "reactstrap": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/6.0.1/reactstrap.full.min.js"
  },

to config.json it will resolve reactstrap dependancy in spfx

Comment: It worked.
Tried adding @types/reactstrap , but that didn't work.

added =>  "reactstrap": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/7.1.0/reactstrap.full.min.js"